# PostgreSql, unterminated quoted string

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am using Postgresql Db. i got this error for using ' on a text,

> unterminated quoted string at or near "'\'')"

it is my function call:

```
SELECT "public"."sendMessage"(12152015, 12584, 1258487, 13960614093221020, '\'')
```

how can i insert these characters into db without any problem??

Comment: This is also documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to quote a single quote is to repeat it, not to escape it:

```
SELECT "public"."sendMessage"(12152015, 12584, 1258487, 13960614093221020, '''')
                                                                            ^^
```

Comment: and what about double quotation and other special characters user can enter??

Comment: @Saeed.At Double quotes are not special characters in a string literal.

Comment: Single quote is the only character that you have to escape. It's better to use parameterized queries and have the database library do this for you.

Comment: @Saeed.At: see the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: `Also, a single quote can be included in an escape string by writing \', in addition to the normal way of ''.`@a_horse_with_no_name , but it does not true, is it?